# If statement not executing if the one is false Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have a bunch if statements, If any of them is true a card is created and displayed in HTML, the problem is that when the top if statements are false the rest will not be executed.

```
      if (pr) {
        createViewCard('Purchase Requisition', 'veiwpr');
      }

      if (pc) {
        createViewCard('Petty Cash', 'veiwpc');
      }

      if (cpr) {
        createViewCard('Cheque/Payment Requisition', 'veiwcpr');
      }

      if (ba) {
        createViewCard('Business Advance Form', 'veiwba');
      }

      if (cqc) {
        createViewCard('Comparison Quotation Chart', 'veiwcqc');
      }
```

The if values are obtained from PHP, if a value in a table exists i set the corresponding Javascript variable to true :

```
$cr_SQL = "SELECT * FROM created_requests WHERE request_id='$rID'";
$cr_results = mysqli_query($dbcon, $cr_SQL);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($cr_results)) {

  if ($row['name'] == "pr_created") {
    echo "<script>";
    echo "var pr = true;";
    echo "</script>";

    echo $row['name'];
  }

  if ($row['name'] == "ba_created") {
    echo "<script>";
    echo "var ba = true;";
    echo "</script>";

    echo $row['name'];
  }

  if ($row['name'] == "cpr_created") {
    echo "<script>";
    echo "var cpr = true;";
    echo "</script>";

    echo $row['name'];
  }

  if ($row['name'] == "cqc_created") {
    echo "<script>";
    echo "var cqc = true;";
    echo "</script>";

    echo $row['name'];
  }

  if ($row['name'] == "pc_created") {
    echo "<script>";
    echo "var pc = true;";
    echo "</script>";

    echo $row['name'];
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think what you're describing is actually heppening. Show a [mcve] of the problem, because in the code you show, the latter ifs will still be checked even if the top ones are true. There's either something else going on, or the variables you're checking aren't actually truthy.

Comment: @Carcigenicate agreed, all the if statements will run in this case so thats clearly not the problem.

Comment: Not exactly related, but useful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/array and http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: From your code, we have no way to help you. But.. try a `console.log(pr)` in the top `if`, and you'll see what triggered it to be `true`.

Comment: you can debug  and  check what exactly `pr` is having may be bcos of some space it is not executing if condition

Comment: all the if  statements execute if all of them are true.

Comment: @Harry Again though, what you're describing can't happen with the code you've provided. `console.log(pr, pc, cpr, ba, cqc)` before the ifs shows the values that you expect?

Comment: Have you tried adding `console.log`s inside of the if bodies to ensure that they aren't running? `createViewCard` might be bugged.

Answer (score 0):

Doing it like this fixed it.

```
 <?php
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($cr_results)) {
          if ($row['name'] == "pr_created") {
            echo "createViewCard('Purchase Requisition', 'veiwpr');";
          }

          if ($row['name'] == "ba_created") {
            echo "createViewCard('Business Advance Form', 'veiwba');";
          }

          if ($row['name'] == "cpr_created") {
            echo "createViewCard('Cheque/Payment Requisition', 'veiwcpr');";
          }

          if ($row['name'] == "cqc_created") {
            echo "createViewCard('Comparison Quotation Chart', 'veiwcqc');";
          }

          if ($row['name'] == "pc_created") {
            echo "createViewCard('Petty Cash', 'veiwpc');";
          }
        }

        ?>
```